# Need to access Nokia 200 Phone memory

Tags: nokia

I want to access my Nokia 200 's Internal phone memory using ubuntu. How do I do it?
Whenever I connect my phone via usb I get 3 options to choose from in my phone

- Nokia Suite -> lets me access my phone via Nokia PC suite in windows
- Media Transfer -> Mostly does the same work
- Mass Storage -> lets me access only the Card in my phone

Now I want to access my phones Internal memory via USB in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/
Download nokuntu - it's unofficial Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu

OR

```
apt-get install obexftp  openobex-apps
lsusb
```

Second command will show you sth like

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0421:043a Nokia Mobile Phones
```

You need only:

```
VendorID = 0421
ProductID = 043a
```

Than open next file:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/040-permissions.rules
```

And add this lines:

```
BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="VendorID", SYSFS{idProduct}=="ProductID", GROUP="plugdev", USER="yourUserNname"
```

On your desktop create startup button with command:

```
java -jar /home/YOURUSERNAME/obexftp-frontend-0.6.1-bin/OBEXFTPFrontend.jar
```

Now run `/usr/bin/obexftp` and go to Transport and select USB, Value 1

And run startuo button from desktop. You should see disk C: from your phone

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: What's the problem? Does it give some errors?

Comment: http://ubuntu-stash.blogspot.in/2008/12/transfer-files-to-and-from-your-nokia.html

Comment: error 'Can't connect to phone'

Comment: Did you select Nokia Suite? Does lsusb show this phone?

Comment: yes i selected all of then turn by turn also lsusb shows this phone

Comment: lsusb for nokia phone -> Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0421:059b Nokia Mobile Phones